# "onmouseup"の不具合の原因

Tags: javascript

下記のコードは、ボタンを押したときの矢印の色は『ライトスカイブルー』に、戻したときは『レッド』になるように設定したものですが、連打して元に戻した場合に、たまに『ライトスカイブルー』のままになっていることがあります。原因と，また解決策があれば、教えていただけませんでしょうか。

```
<INPUT id="Left" TYPE="button" VALUE="<" style="background-color:black; color:red;" onMouseDown="document.getElementById('Left').style.color='lightskyblue'" onMouseUp="document.getElementById('Left').style.color='red';">
```

Comment: 試してみましたが再現しませんでした。例えば、`getElementById('Left')` の
代わりに`this`を使ってみたらどうでしょうか？`onMouseDown="this.style.color='lightskyblue'"`

Comment: 何か冗漫な書き方だと思っていましたが、それでいいのですね。
再現は、しますが…それと、それでも連打すると、元に戻らないことがあります。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onmouseup`が発生する前に、カーソルがボタンから外れてしまったのでしょう。
ボタンをクリックしたままカーソルを動かし、ボタンでない領域で離すと再現しました。
これの対処として、質問者様の書き方を尊重すれば、たとえば`onmouseleave`イベントでカーソルが外れてしまったときにも赤色に戻す、という動作を実装する方法があります。

```html
<input id="Left" type="button" value="<"
    style="background-color:black; color:red;"
    onmousedown="this.style.color='lightskyblue'"
    onmouseup="this.style.color='red';"
    onmouseleave="this.style.color='red';"
    />
```

あるいは、cssで`:active`疑似セレクタを利用して以下のようにすることもできます。
個人的にはjsの必要ないこちらがベターかと思います。

```css
#Left
{
  background-color: black;
  color: red;
}

#Left:active
{
  color: lightskyblue;
}
```

```html
<input id="Left" type="button" value="<" />
```

また細かいことですが、htmlのタグ名および属性名は小文字にするほうがよいです。

Comment: 回答をありがとうございました。
onmouseupが発生する前に、カーソルがボタンから外れたのですね。
"onmouseleave"とは、こういったときにも活用できるイベントですね。
":active疑似セレクタ"というものを、活用するという方法もあるのですか。
解決策は、あるものですね。助かりました。
それと、確かにhtmlのタグ名等は、大文字になっていますね。コピペを繰り返しているうちに、いつの間にか大文字に変わってしまうという現象があります。

Comment: ちょっと１つ気付いたのですが、:active疑似セレクタを設定したボタンは、"無効"にできないのでしょうか。disabledを埋め込んでも、この効果はありません。

Comment: うまくいきました。:disabled擬似セレクタも追加するといいようです。
お騒がせしました。

Comment: 問題がないようであれば余計なコメントですが、要素がdisabledになるケースを考慮すれば回答にある`#Left:active`を`#Left:not(:disabled):active`と書き換えることで期待する動作が得られますね。

Comment: そのようにも書けるのですか。こちらがコンピューターが好みそうな書き方のようですので、活用させていただきます。